Gstreamer filesink and videosink tee pipeline
I am trying to make a pipeline that will show a video stream to the screen and also save this stream to a file.
This is my pipeline:
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=snow ! videoconvert ! tee name=t \
    t. ! queue ! autovideosink \
    t. ! queue ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4

It displays exactly one frame to the screen and then freezes. Also it creates the output.mp4 file, but it is not ended properly so it can't be played.
This is the output I get from this command:
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.023079395 370034 0x7ac4fc000b90 WARN              aggregator gstaggregator.c:2283:gst_aggregator_query_latency_unlocked:<mp4mux0> Latency query failed
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.023753805 370034 0x7ac4fc0010a0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:4089:gst_element_decorate_stream_id_internal:<videotestsrc0> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

Have you got any idea?

This question is similar to: Gstreamer - display and record video using Tee element hangs. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
